# iOS Does CGBitmapContextCreate copy data?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, cgbitmapcontextcreate

I have written this piece of code:

```
 bitmapData = calloc(1, bitmapByteCount );
 context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                 pixelsWide,
                                 pixelsHigh,
                                 8,
                                 bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                 colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaOnly);
```

When I do this, is CGBitmapContext copying my bitmapData, so after these lines i should be writting

```
free(bitmapData);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need `bitmapData` don't free it. If you don't need it, pass `NULL` as a parameter instead and Quartz will allocate memory itself (iOS 4.0 and later).

> **data**: A pointer to the destination in memory where the drawing is to be rendered. The size of this memory block should be at least (bytesPerRow*height) bytes.
>   In iOS 4.0 and later, and Mac OS X v10.6 and later, you can pass NULL if you want Quartz to allocate memory for the bitmap. This frees you from managing your own memory, which reduces memory leak issues.

But Quartz doesn't copy `bitmapData`, it does the rendering there. After you release `context` you should free that memory.

Edit: In one of Apple sample [projects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/QuartzCache/Listings/Stage3_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003663-Stage3_c-DontLinkElementID_9), memory is freed, but not immediately:

```
float drawStage3(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect)
{
    // ...
    cachedData = malloc( (((ScaledToWidth * 32) + 7) / 8) * ScaledToHeight);
    // ...
    bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(cachedData /* data */,
    // ...
    CFRelease(bitmapContext);
    // ...
    // Clean up
    CFRelease(cachedImage);
    free(cachedData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Your code is allocating a block of memory via [calloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/)- you own that block of memory.  So, you own [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/free/)ing that memory.  The CGBitmapContext create is just creating a context using the block of memory that you created (which is why you have to pass it in).  When you are done with that block of memory you should free it.

I would do CFRelease on the context first.  Whatever resources the context creates will be taken care of by the CFRelease.

The "Create Rule" in the [Core Foundation Memory Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH) Says:

> Core Foundation functions have names that indicate when you own a
>   returned object:
>
> Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name;
>   Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name. If
>   you own an object, it is your responsibility to relinquish ownership
>   (using CFRelease) when you have finished with it.

Comment: I know that i should release context, but do i have to free my bitmapData explicitly, does context copy that array of bytes, or just take reference to it?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood, updating the answer